# How to manage users created with AWS Amplify Authentication

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, vue.js, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

I am attempting to build an AWS Amplify authentication page with Vue.js based on the following tutorial: https://dev.to/dabit3/how-to-build-production-ready-vue-authentication-23mk. I am configuring the `profile.vue` component to pass user information associated with the authenticated user to the template. In the tutorial, a method called `Auth.currentAuthenticatedUser` returns a `user` object containing metadata about the logged-in user. This metadata is accessed by appending `.username` to `name` in the template. Here is an example of that component from the above tutorial with the `Auth.currentAuthenticatedUser` method:

```
<template>
  <h1>Welcome, {{user.username}}</h1>
</template>

<script>
import { Auth } from 'aws-amplify'

export default {
  name: 'Profile',
  data() {
    return {
      user: {}
    }
  },
  beforeCreate() {
    Auth.currentAuthenticatedUser()
      .then(user => {
        this.user = user
      })
      .catch(() => console.log('not signed in...'))
  }
}
</script>
```

My question is: Which AWS service actually stores that user data once the user is created? Is there a dashboard similar to Amplify or Cognito that is used to manage user information in the form of collections?

Comment: Did you resolve the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using Amplify and the [auth class](https://aws-amplify.github.io/amplify-js/api/classes/authclass.html#signin) the `aws-amplify` npm package provides I believe the answer is you're already using Cognito. You should be able to view your users in Cognito already.

Comment: Thanks for the followup. I am logged into the Cognito service on AWS and am inside the user pool environment that was generated when I created the project. i should see a list of registered users in this window, correct? I am not seeing users.

Comment: thanks again for the feedback. Would you be willing to take a look at another Vue.js/AWS-Amplify problem? : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59001855/how-to-retrieve-currentuser-data-with-vue-js-aws-amplify-and-mongodb